# Отрицательный остаток от деления Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему остаток от деления в этих случаях выводится отрицательный? Он же не может быть отрицательным.

```
print((-1) % (-109))  # выводит -1
print(1 % (-109))     # выводит -108
```

По присланной [в комментарии ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python) обсуждается лишь логика, не затрагивая вопроса отрицательного остатка, а также приводится мат. формулировка, согласно которой одно из условий гласит, что остаток не может быть отрицательным:
`b*q + r = a` and `0 <= r < b`

Comment: Потому что может.

Comment: [Клац](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python)

Comment: По присланной в комментарии Mr. Brightside ссылке обсуждается лишь логика самого деления, не затрагивая вопроса отрицательного остатка, а также приводится мат. формулировка, согласно которой одно из условий гласит, что остаток не может быть отрицательным: b*q + r = a and 0 <= r < b

Comment: [Здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) рассмотрены разные интерпретации `modulo/remainder` в разных языках

Comment: [Знак остатка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0).